# pandas groupby on a values based on n-1 index record

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the following data:

```
Name, Group, Value

Mike, A, 0
Peter, A, 5
Adam, A, 12
Jared, A, 18
Bob, B, 0
Jason, B, 1
Dan, B, 9
```

Is it feasible to get the following result in Series (or DataFrame on which the computed series is appended to the last column)?

```
0
5
7
6
0
1
8
```

These values are computed by the record's `Value` minus the record's one previous record (i.e. if its record is on `Adam`, it means `Peter`'s record)'s `Value`. However, I also want to get it on the basis of the `Group` variable, which means I don't want to get `Bob`'s `Value` based on the `Jared`'s `Value`, since those two records's `Group` value is different - I only compute it within each specific `Group` variable.

I'm not sure whether it can be done only on pandas. I use pandas 0.13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the diff groupby method directly:

```
In [23]: df.groupby('Group').Value.diff(1).fillna(0)
Out[23]:
0    0
1    5
2    7
3    6
4    0
5    1
6    8
dtype: float64
```

which does the same thing as using shift and subtract:

```
In [21]: df.groupby('Group').Value.shift()
Out[21]:
0   NaN
1     0
2     5
3    12
4   NaN
5     0
6     1
dtype: float64
```

and fill in the NaNs with 0:

```
In [22]: (df.Value - df.groupby('Group').Value.shift()).fillna(0)
Out[22]:
0    0
1    5
2    7
3    6
4    0
5    1
6    8
dtype: float64
```

#### Original answer:

You just compare it to the shifted value column:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')

In [12]: res = df.Value - df.Value.shift()

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
0   NaN
1     5
2     7
3     6
4   -18
5     1
6     8
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

It looks like you want to make the NaN and the negatives 0:

```
In [14]: res[pd.isnull(res) | (res < 0)] = 0

In [15]: res
Out[15]:
0    0
1    5
2    7
3    6
4    0
5    1
6    8
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Whoa! That's super awesome! I don't like the syntax though... Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @user2360798 I prefer using [] syntax for accessing columns: `df.groupby('Group')['Value'].shift()`, do you find that syntax better?

Comment: Ah, I was talking about calling a method (`fillna`) on an object wrapped by a curly bracket, which I am usually not a fan of. I prefer using `apply` as suggested by Karl.

Comment: @user2360798 true, it's not very pythonic... you can always do the fillna on the result on the next line. shame shift doesn't have a default value arg. :S

Comment: @user2360798 remembered the diff method does this, much nicer!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
print df

  Group   Name  Value
0     A   Mike      0
1     A  Peter      5
2     A   Adam     12
3     A  Jared     18
4     B    Bob      0
5     B  Jason      1
6     B    Dan      9

same_group = df.Group == df.Group.shift(1)
df['new'] = (df.Value - df.Value.shift(1)).where(same_group,0)

print df

  Group   Name  Value  new
0     A   Mike      0    0
1     A  Peter      5    5
2     A   Adam     12    7
3     A  Jared     18    6
4     B    Bob      0    0
5     B  Jason      1    1
6     B    Dan      9    8
```

Or you could use shift within a `groupby`/`apply`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(1))
print df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the `apply` solution!